# Совмещение front-end фреймворков с паттерном MVC

Tags: php, javascript, mvc

Из front-end фреймворков выбрал Vue.js. Назрел такой вопрос: раньше URL путь формировался в файле routes.php, который возвращал массив, к примеру, такого вида:

```
'partners/login' => 'partner/signin',
'partners/logout' => 'partner/logout',
'partners/cabinet/qa' => 'partnerCabinet/qa',
'partners/cabinet/ads/([0-9]+)' => 'partnerCabinet/viewads/$1',
'partners/cabinet/ads' => 'partnerCabinet/ads',
'partners/cabinet' => 'partnerCabinet/index'
```

т.е. слева URL путь от корня сайта, справа контроллер/action, обрабатывающий данный URL. Action, для примера, выглядит вот так:

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    // Проверка доступа
    self::checkAdmin();

    // Подключаем вид
    require_once(ROOT . '/views/admin/index.php');
    return true;
}
```

Т.е. все views лежали в папке views и выводились оттуда же. А в Vue.js, как я понимаю, есть свой объект Router-link, который отвечает за URL. Скажите, как правильно интегрировать Vue.js в проект с моделью MVC?

Comment: НА самом деле у Вас 2 типа роутеров. 1 обрабатывается на сервере в `routes.php` второй - на клиенте (в браузере). И тут необходимо смотреть от задач, которые Вам надо реализовать. Если это singlePage  то роутинг должен быть  Vue.js, задачи требуют реализации других страниц , то обработка на сервере.

Comment: Так же может быть такая ситуация, будут и singlePage и обычный роутинг. И тогда Вы можете комбинировать. То есть у Вас будет несколько приложений на Vue.js. С vue.js не знаком, но из документации следует, что фреймворк предназначен для пользовательских интерфейсов так и для SPA. Скорее всего в первую очередь он ориентирован на обычные страницы(роутинг на сервере)

Comment: @KonstantinOkhotnick т.е. для реализации, к примеру, регистрации и авторизации, мне нужно сделать для обработки данных на сервере файл в серверном routes.php, а для вывода пользовательского интерфейса сделать уже на js во vue.js, верно? Так и идет - данные поступают из запросов vue.js к серверному routes.php, а затем уже обрабатываются на vue?

Comment: Да, только, наверное, аяксом данные получать надо будет.